# Output of one view function to another in django

Tags: django, view

I have a view function which validates a form and get values from it.

I want to use the values stored in the first view function in another view function.

can anyone please tell me how can it be done as I am a newbie to Django.

Comment: What do you mean the "values stored in the first view function"? Are you storing these values in a database somewhere? Or do you mean purely local variables? Are you saying to want to call another function? Or do you want to be able to go to the first url, do something, then go to a second url, and have the same info there?

Comment: hi daniel, no i am not storing it in any database. ya those are local variables.

Comment: my scenario is that i am filling a login form thruh one view and it redirects to the other url which calls the othr view which has other fields and as soon i submit the second form i call my python script in the second view which also needs the field values of the first form as argument. I can't merge both forms as one as per the requirement

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need django [wizard form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)